# Why do I have CORS client side errors using AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem serving private files with cloudfront (signed cookies).

From postman it works, but if I try to show an image from HTML (I set the cookies before show it) the following happens:

1. If I add crossOrigin = "use-credentials" to the image tag then I got a CORS error "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
2. If I don't add the cross origin then I have a 403 error.

The S3 configuration is:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
     <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have only 1 behavior in the cloudfront distribution and this what I have:
[image]

and finally this is how I generate the cookies (server side)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate on "Allowed HTTP Methods" to activate `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS` instad only `GET, HEAD`.